# Creating an RPM with CMake will result in unusable system

Tags: linux, bash, cmake

Currently I am moving my packaging from a bunch of weird scripts into CMake using CPack. The Debian and TGZ work really nice but the RPM is giving me troubles... When I install the RPM that has been created on openSUSE 15.1 then it will result in an unusable system (no even `ls` can be executed anymore and I cannot dig into why as of not beeing able to open a `konsole` or something).

Here is my CPack code (ive stripped anything with DEB and TGZ for readability):

```
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB;TGZ;RPM")

# Common packaging params
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "mytool")
set(VERSION "${ver_maj}.${ver_min}.${ver_build}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION ${VERSION})
set(CPACK_SET_DESTDIR true)

# RPM packaging params
set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_SUMMARY "Summary")
set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_NAME "mytool")
set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_VERSION "${VERSION}")
set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_LICENSE "Proprietary")
set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_GROUP "Applications/Internet")
set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_VENDOR "me, myself and I")
set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_URL "https://myurl555.com/")
set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION "MyDesc")
set(CPACK_RPM_POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_FILE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/make/rpm/post")
set(CPACK_RPM_POST_UNINSTALL_SCRIPT_FILE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/make/rpm/postun")
set(CPACK_RPM_PRE_UNINSTALL_SCRIPT_FILE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/make/rpm/preun")
```

The post script:

```
if [ -x %{_bindir}/gtk-update-icon-cache-2.0 ]; then
  %{_bindir}/gtk-update-icon-cache-2.0 %{_datadir}/icons/hicolor > /dev/null 2>&1 || true
fi
if [ -x %{_bindir}/gtk-update-icon-cache ]; then
  %{_bindir}/gtk-update-icon-cache %{_datadir}/icons/hicolor > /dev/null 2>&1 || true
fi

SYSTEMD=`pidof systemd || echo '0'`
if [ "${SYSTEMD}" != "0" ]; then
    if [ -e /etc/systemd/system/mytool.service ]; then
        rm /etc/systemd/system/mytool.service
    fi
    cp /usr/share/mytool/files/systemd/mytool.service /etc/systemd/system/mytool.service
    systemctl daemon-reload
    systemctl enable mytool
fi

service mytool start

if [ -x %{_bindir}/update-desktop-database ]; then
    %{_bindir}/update-desktop-database > /dev/null 2>&1 || true
fi
```

postun:

```
if [ -x %{_bindir}/gtk-update-icon-cache-2.0 ]; then
  %{_bindir}/gtk-update-icon-cache-2.0 %{_datadir}/icons/hicolor > /dev/null 2>&1 || true
fi
if [ -x %{_bindir}/gtk-update-icon-cache ]; then
  %{_bindir}/gtk-update-icon-cache %{_datadir}/icons/hicolor > /dev/null 2>&1 || true
fi

SYSTEMD=`pidof systemd || echo '0'`
if [ "${SYSTEMD}" != "0" ]; then
    systemctl daemon-reload
fi
```

preun:

```
service mytool stop > /dev/null 2>&1 || true

SYSTEMD=`pidof systemd || echo '0'`
if [ "${SYSTEMD}" != "0" ]; then
    systemctl disable mytool > /dev/null 2>&1 || true
    rm /etc/systemd/system/mytool.service
fi
```

I cannot see any reason why something like this happens. What happens to the system is that when using alt+f2 and running for example `konsole` then it will tell me that it cannot make `konsole` executable. The executable `/usr/bin/konsole` is still there, the groups of the user did not change, etc.

Comment: Why the `%` symbol before variable names? Shouldn't it be `$`

Comment: thats RPM scripts... it will be replaced by RPMBUILD. It wont be in the compiled scripts...